# folder names organized by date, how to find the latest?

Tags: ruby, command-line

Trying to do this with command line or with ruby, but I have a number of folders which their names correspond to a date (they are db dumps), I want to find the latest folder and do something with it.

Example:
`/dumps` has folders:
`/dumps/2015-08-09`, `/dumps/2015-08-11`, `/dumps/2015-08-20`

How can I do so in command line or perhaps ruby?

Thanks!

Comment: an example of the data you're working with would help a lot

Comment: show us an example of folder names please.

Comment: Updated to show examples

Comment: can't you use ls -lrt and than get the last line?

Comment: in Ruby you could just do `Dir['/dumps/*'].sort.last #=> "/dumps/2015-08-20"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the subfolders have sensible names:

```
last_folder = Dir.glob("/dumps/*").sort.last
```

Comment: Hahaha I just added this as a comment.

Comment: I ended up doing something like this: `Dir['dumps/**'].sort_by{|x| Time.new(x.split('/').last).to_i}.last`

Comment: Don't know why you need that complexity: the date format %Y-%m-%d sorts perfectly well lexically.

Answer (score 0):

use ls

```
ls -lrt dumps/*
```

should work

and than you can use `tail -n1` to get the last line

Comment: Hmm, I need to reuse that name though. How can I get it to output?